# Making PNG files with standalone no longer works

Tags: pdftex, standalone, conversion

To do troubleshooting I have simplified my problem to the bones.  So I start my tex file with

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
```

If I call `pdflatex` with

```
pdflatex.exe -shell-escape file_name
```

it returns

```
'magick' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!

 ) )
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 3 was incomplete)
No pages of output.
```

However, if I call `magick` directly from the very same folder

```
magick file_name.pdf file_name.png
```

everything is fine.

Both miktex and magick folders are in the path.  I have run out of debugging ideas.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

in standalone.cfg file, I add :

```
\standaloneconfig{convert={convertexe={D:/my/path/to/ImageMagick/magick.exe}}}
```

and it's work fine.

Comment: Sorry, did not help.